# Node js | Use external file to send as response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, npm

I saw a similar question, but I'm looking for a way to do it manually. I don't want to use express or another library to do it.

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.end('<h1 >Hi!</h1>'); //I want to to fetch a file ex: index.html
});

server.listen(9334);
```

How would i do that? Also as a sub-question, just because I'm curious. Is it possible to use jQuery ajax to fetch this file?

Comment: that snip doesn't use express... you can replace the string with fs.readFileSync("theFile.ext"), preferably loading just once at boot unless theFile changes...

Comment: I know it's not using Express. I'm just saying that i want to load an html file as a response, Without using Express or another library. And fs is another library. I want to do it manually.

Comment: Ah but fs is a core module of node js, that could be a good solution.

Comment: I like this, you can put it as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do is using 'fs'.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    fs.createReadStream("filename.ext").pipe(res);
});

server.listen(9334);
```

This is also good because if the file is big the data is streamed to the response instead of waiting for the read operation to be completed. Although you might have to set 'Content-Type' header in some cases.